# Is it possible to launch an android application activity when the phone starts?

Tags: java, android

Im attempting to build an android application and one of the key features to this application is for it to be able to launch an activity automatically when the phone starts, I see some apps on my phone that already do this, any help would be great so that I can atleast research this a little better through the sdk, thanks!

Comment: something like that? >>[click](http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup)<<

Comment: oh sweet, this will help too thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to implement BroadCastreceiver like this:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            Intent launch = new Intent(context, AcitivityToLaunch.class);
            launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(launch);
        }
    }
}
```

In your manifest add this:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.PhoneStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```